# <embed> instead <img> tag HTML

Tags: tags, embed, image

I want to make a function that allows me to display an image or a swf, I noticed that the embed tag I can show both, I lnvestigated and got nothing about it, there is some downside in using it?

example:

```
<embed src="image.png" />
<embed src="flash.swf" />
```

Both work even without including the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but, however, `<embed>` tag isn't recommended to be used.

Answer (score 4):

You really should use the `<img>` tag for images and not `<embed>`. Instead, figure out what the file type is first and then use either `<img>` OR `<embed>` depending on the file type.